# Rego: how to specify not having either of multiple conditions

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

How can I validate the existence of two separate keys in Rego for OPA? Currently, I'm using the `not` operator like so:

```
deny["Containers must specify readiness and liveness probes"] {
  not container.readinessProbe
  not container.livenessProbe
}
```

However, this only denies up containers without both `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe`. How do I specify to deny a container missing *either* of the two keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case I think it makes sense to just have a deny rule for each:

```
deny["Containers must specify readiness probes"] {
  not container.readinessProbe
}

deny["Containers must specify liveness probes"] {
  not container.livenessProbe
}
```

With Rego policies the rules are OR'd together, and the rule body statements are AND'd. So if you are trying to express an OR condition typically look to have a rule for each case.

Comment: Thanks, I considered this but wanted to avoid it because `container` has some boilerplate that I'd have to repeat, though perhaps I should make another question for that